# What is runtime type of null value?

Tags: apex

It is not System.Object or System.sObject, because we can pass null to methods which require System.String as a parameter, and cannot pass System.Object there.

Following code demonstrated difference between System.Object and th type of the null literal:

```
'abc'.contains(null); // compiler does not complain
 boolean b;
'abc'.contains(b?null:null); // compiler does not complain
 Object o = b?null:null;
'abc'.contains(o); // compiler error
```

So the question is, what type null literal and expression `b?null:null` have?
Is there a standard library function like typOf, so that I could call `typOf(null)`?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context, maybe share some of the offending code, it'll help troubleshoot but it sounds like you are sending a null argument to a method.

Comment: I sort of get what you are asking.so `null` is just a blank reference i guess which does not have memory allocated.The type we say is of reference and not of the `null` value.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Already linked to that in my answer. :)

Comment: Are you looking for more detail than is included in the existing answers? Can you [edit] your post to specify what is missing if so?

Answer (score 4):

I think what it comes down to is that the compiler doesn't handle the typing for you with an `Object` the way that it does with `NULL`.

It would be possible for the language designers to build this functionality, but would be extremely complex since you can use the Object type to create variables and assign them values, but you can't with the NULL type.

The literal `NULL` always has the same value and this value is applicable to all types. An `Object` can have many different values which are mostly not applicable to other types.

---

As for using an `Object` as a `String`, if you do know that your object variable does in fact happen to be a string (or at least should be a string), you can indicate that to the compiler by using a typecast.

```
Object o = 'A String Literal';
try{
    ((String) o).subString(0,8);
} catch(TypeException e){
    ...
}
```

Comment: 1.2 is a Decimal, and 1.2d is a Double. The compiler masks this difference for you, because they are generally interchangeable. They are *not* the same thing. Notably, assigning a Double to a Decimal *may cause data loss*. Null, conversely, is always the same thing (namely, the absence of any thing). You might consider it a parent of Object (e.g. it represents all possible types).

Comment: As a somewhat arbitrary example, consider this runtime exception: `Double b = 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999.0d;
Decimal a = (Decimal)b;`

Comment: @sfdcfox True, all good points.

Comment: @sfdcfox Decided to get rid of that part. Looking back on it now, the compiler's handling of numeric literals isn't that great of an analogy.

Answer (score 3):

It matches every type. Take a look at [What is null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707322/what-is-null-in-java) for some more background.

> There is also a special *null* type, the type of the expression `null`, which has no name. Because the *null* type has no name, it is impossible to declare a variable of the *null* type or to cast to the *null* type. The `null` reference is the only possible value of an expression of *null* type. The `null` reference can always be cast to any reference type. In practice, the programmer can ignore the *null* type and just pretend that `null` is merely a special literal that can be of any reference type.

---

Also, try the following with any right operand as the `ReferenceType`:

```
null instanceof String
```

You will get the message:

> Operation instanceof is always true since an instance of NULL is always an instance of String

---

As noted by [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox), a specific instance of `null` is not of any type specifically:

```
String s = null;
Object o = s;
system.assertEquals(false, o instanceof String);
```

Comment: True, but you might want to mention that a null value in a variable always returns false (at least in the later API versions).

Comment: I don't follow you. You're saying a specific `null` instance is not an `instanceof` anything? @sfdcfox

Comment: `Object o; System.assertEquals(false, o instanceof String);`

Comment: Well, that doesn't have any reason be `true` anyway. Tricky because instantiation is what lends `o` its `Type` in the first place. To my eye, the question is centered around the `null` reference specifically.

Comment: Believe me, I'm glad it's no longer true. It created all sorts of problems when it used to be. I just think it's useful to note that "null", as a reference, is both no type (as I demonstrated), and every type (as you demonstrated). It's a very magical type, indeed.

Comment: I know what null is in Java - thanks to comprehensive language specification. Apex deviates from Java in many ways, and has no specification. This is why I am asking this question.

Comment: In this case, I do not believe there is deviation. It is a solid explanation of how the `null` reference works in `Apex`.